# Integration with variable in numerator

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int\frac{x^5}{\sqrt{25-x^2}}dx$$

I tried to do it with substitution but couldn't get ride of $x^5$ in the numerator.

Comment: Try solving for $x$ and back-substituting in your $u$-substitution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can actually be done without a trigonometric substitution.

Let $u = 25-x^2$. Then, $du = -2x\,dx$, and so, $x\,dx = -\dfrac{1}{2}\,du$.

Also, $x^2 = 25-u$, and so, $x^4 = (25-u)^2$.

Hence, $\displaystyle\int\dfrac{x^5}{\sqrt{25-x^2}}\,dx$ $= \displaystyle\int\dfrac{x^4}{\sqrt{25-x^2}}x\,dx$ $= -\dfrac{1}{2}\displaystyle\int\dfrac{(25-u)^2}{\sqrt{u}}\,du$

$= -\dfrac{1}{2}\displaystyle\int\dfrac{u^2-50u+625}{\sqrt{u}}\,du$ $= -\dfrac{1}{2}\displaystyle\int u^{3/2}-50u^{1/2}+625u^{-1/2}\,du$,

which is easy to integrate using the power rule.

Comment: Yup that's what I was wrong in. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Try the substitution:
$$x=5\sin{u}\implies dx=5\cos{u}\,du$$
$$\therefore \sqrt{25-x^2}=\sqrt{25-25\sin^2{u}}=5\cos{u}$$
$$\therefore\int\frac{x^5}{\sqrt{25-x^2}}\,dx=5\int 625\sin^5{u}\,du=3125\int\sin^5{u}\,du$$

Comment: I've done it, I know this function would use arcsin trig function formula. But I don't know what to do with x^5 on top.

Comment: @Rahul Can you integrate this?

Comment: Yes thanks this worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I like to motivate trigonometric substitution using a figure. Here you want some trig function in the triangle to be $\sqrt{25-x^2}$; that is most naturally treated as one of the legs. Then the hypotenuse must be $5$ while the other leg is $x$. Put the leg of length $x$ opposite the acute angle $\theta$. Then the figure tells you that $x=5\sin(\theta)$ and $\sqrt{25-x^2}=5\cos(\theta)$. Using these substitutions makes your integral fairly straightforward.

To be a bit specific, since $x=5\sin(\theta)$, you can just replace the $x$ in the numerator with this. You then replace $\sqrt{25-x^2}$ with $5 \cos(\theta)$ and replace $dx$ as usual.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Make the change $t=\sqrt{25-x^2}.$ Note that $$dt=-\frac{x}{t}dx$$ and $$x^4=(25-t^2)^2.$$ Thus

$$\int \frac{x^5}{\sqrt{25-x^2}}dx=-\int (25-t^2)^2dt.$$